# Rearrange dl list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, list

I have a DL list with a title in the DT and information in the DD. Like this:

```
<div class="message">  
  <dl>
     <dt>Title 1</dt>
     <dd>Information 1</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
     <dt>Title 2</dt>
     <dd>Information 2</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
     <dt>Title 3</dt>
     <dd>Information 3</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I want to **move** "Title 3" and "Information 3" to the top using Javascript/jQuery (I don't have access to the HTML). I have no clue of how to do that or if that's even possible. Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: How to move? Programmatically? Drag and drop? Sorting?

Comment: I want to move the list item "programmatically" by selecting an item and "tell it where to go". I don't want to make the list items "movable". I was given this list by another person and if I want to make any changes I have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move it programatically - ie moving the last child of the `message` div to the first position

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0];
el.insertBefore(el.lastElementChild, el.firstChild);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuopyndg/)

---

Using jQuery

```
$('.message').prepend($('.message > dl').last())
```

Comment: yes.... then it looks like `lastElementChild` might be buggy there(from MDN) where it could return a comment node